# Standalone EJB client lookup in Glassfish4

Tags: ejb-3.0, glassfish-4

Spent half a day solving the problem of ejb client lookup in glassfish 4.

The bean:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class TestBean implements TestRemote{
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "testunit")
    private EntityManager em;
    public String sayHello() {return "hello";}
}
```

The remote business interface:

```
@javax.ejb.Remote
public interface TestRemote {
    public String sayHello();
}
```

Client lookup code, tried the following variants (the client can be in another machine, but in this test they are running on the same machine):

```
new InitialContext().lookup("java:global/myproject/TestBean");
new InitialContext().lookup("java:global/myproject/TestRemote");
new InitialContext().lookup("TestRemote");
new InitialContext().lookup("TestBean");
new InitialContext().lookup(TestBean.class.getName());
```

The project is deployed as a war (myproject.war).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
new InitialContext().lookup("com.example.TestRemote");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using glassFish, it normally says what the portable JNDI name is in the logs e.g:

```
INFO:   EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB ProductsBean: [java:global/products-ejb/ProductsBean, java:global/products-ejb/ProductsBean!com.sample.product.ejb.ProductsRemote]
```

so yours will be along the lines of:

```
java:global/<ejb-module-name>/TestBean
```

This looks similar to your question but I could not tell whether "myproject" was the Enterprise Application Name or the EJB Module name...

or

```
java:global/<enterpriseApplicationName>/<ejb-module-name>/TestBean!<package_of_remote>.TestRemote
```

Comment: And only now I saw that you answered your own question ... :)